# Parse the JSON syntax if it is not parsed well

Tags: c#, json, json.net, win-universal-app

How do I parse the JSON data if it is not well parsed from newtonsoft json. Please refer my below code:

```
var web_uri = new Uri("www.example.com"); 
var resp = await client2.GetAsync(web_uri); 
var resp_to_str = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
var json_obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resp_to_str);
```

Finally i parsed the JSON. now, it produces as expected.

```
   {
        "Sex": "Male",
        "category": "A",
        "ID": 14,
        "created": "2016-03-03",
        "Tag": "2340",
        "members": [{
            "type": "A",
            "name": "fam_mem",
            "state": "ca",
            "Family": {
                "myGuardName": "tony",
                "details": [{
                    "address": "ca",
                    "type": "A"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }



  **RootObject omyclass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json_obj);**
```

Now i am getting error at the above line:
An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Linq.Expressions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)' has some invalid arguments

```
public class Detail
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Family
{
    public string myGuardName { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public Family Family { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public List<Member> members { get; set; }
}

TextBlock.Text = omyclass
```

**I have updated the question**

Comment: `here i see the value from omyclass is null` - Sorry, which field is null?

Comment: the json is not valid, maybe that's why you cannot parse it

Comment: @Rob From debug console i see value from omyclass is null which it should not.

Comment: @kienct89 How do i make sure it generates correct json format

Comment: @louis: I don't think this is what you can control since the json is come from third party website. As I can see in your sample json, it's missing one closing ']' tag.

Comment: @kienct89 I noticed that.. is there any way i could edit the json format after the response?

Comment: @louis: sure thing, after you crawled it, it becomes your string. But you'll need to find out what's missing, I don't think it's an easy task

Comment: @kienct89 Really not sure what causing to be not well formed json.. have to work on converting it to string and modify the data and convert it back to json!

Comment: are you sure you are waiting properly? The json you provided is incomplete at best (and 2 '{' characters in a row are not valid Json anyway). If you call the website from a browser, do you get the same result?

Comment: @A.Chiesa I haven't tried calling website from browser... I am trying to edit website data so that i get proper json format.. i will update it here soon!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) expects a string as an input argument -- but you are not passing in a string.  You are passing in `json_obj` which is a `dynamic` returned by a previous call to deserialize:

```
var json_obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resp_to_str);
var omyclass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json_obj);
```

What `JsonConvert` returns from the first `dynamic` call is in fact a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm) containing a tree of [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) tokens -- not a string.  This causes the [`RuntimeBinderException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.runtimebinderexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) upon making the second call.

There is no need to double-deserialize the JSON string in this manner.  Just pass the `resp_to_str` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>()`:

```
var omyclass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resp_to_str);
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FL2F6).

**Update**

If you want to see all the fields and properties of the deserialized class in a text box, you could re-serialize it to JSON:

```
var reserializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(omyclass, Formatting.Indented);
textBlock2.Text = reserializedJson;
```

If you do

```
textBlock2.Text = omyclass + "----!"
```

You are just showing the [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value for your class.  And since you have not [overridden this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) it will just show the class name.

If you don't want to re-serialize you could use the following extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static StringBuilder ToStringWithReflection<T>(this T obj, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        sb = sb ?? new StringBuilder();

        if (obj == null)
            return sb;

        if (obj is IEnumerable)
        {
            sb.Append("[");
            var first = true;
            foreach (var item in ((IEnumerable)obj))
            {
                if (!first)
                    sb.Append(",");
                sb.Append(item == null ? "" : item.ToString());
                first = false;
            }
            sb.Append("]");
        }
        else
        {
            var type = obj.GetType();
            var fields = type.GetFields();
            var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod(true) != null && p.CanRead);
            var query = fields
                .Select(f => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(f.Name, f.GetValue(obj)))
                .Concat(properties
                    .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Name, p.GetValue(obj, null))));
            sb.Append("{").Append(obj.GetType().Name).Append(": ");
            var first = true;
            foreach (var pair in query)
            {
                if (!first)
                    sb.Append(", ");
                sb.Append(pair.Key).Append(": ");
                if (pair.Value is IEnumerable && !(pair.Value is string))
                    pair.Value.ToStringWithReflection(sb);
                else
                    sb.Append(pair.Value == null ? "null" : pair.Value.ToString());
                first = false;
            }
            sb.Append("}");
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public static string ToStringWithReflection<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return obj.ToStringWithReflection(new StringBuilder()).ToString();
    }
}
```

Then do

```
textBlock2.Text = omyclass.ToStringWithReflection() + "----!"
```

**Update 2**

Or, if you want to include properties from your object hierarchy recursively, you can override the `ToString()` method of each, like so:

```
public class Detail
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return this.ToStringWithReflection(); }
}

public class Family
{
    public string myGuardName { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> details { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return this.ToStringWithReflection(); }
}

public class Member
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public Family Family { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return this.ToStringWithReflection(); }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public List<Member> members { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return this.ToStringWithReflection(); }
}
```

Then the `ToString()` output will be:

```
{RootObject: Sex: Male, category: A, ID: 14, created: 2016-03-03, Tag: 2340, members: [{Member: type: A, name: fam_mem, state: ca, Family: {Family: myGuardName: tony, details: [{Detail: address: ca, type: A}]}}]}
```

Comment: I have passed as mentioned above. But still no luck. I didn't get the output. It's showing blank. No attributes values are fetched.

Comment: @louis - prototype fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FL2F6.  In the fiddle it's shown that the JSON is deserialized and re-serialized successfully.

Comment: am i missing anything above in my code. I am printing it on local machine emulator. Do you have any idea? By the way Thanks for your time!

Comment: You just have some code fragments above, not a complete program.  Can you make a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I could run that shows the problem, and what you want to achieve?

Comment: yeah sure! I am trying to display it on windows 10 emulator which has text view. I have created a textview screen and passing textBlock2.Text = omyclass + "----!" which is not printing or showing those values(output).

Comment: I did go through the code and understood a bit. But i get error at Array.ForEach (error message:array does not contain a definition ForEach). I did import system.

Comment: `Array.ForEach()` is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Do i need to update anything else? Really i couldn't figure out the issue there.

Comment: @louis - I removed `Array.ForEach()` even though it has [been around since .Net 2.0.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  See also the [updated fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5FL2F6).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I really had hard time with C# parsing but with your help i am able to proceed. Please don't delete fiddle, it helped me alot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
var web_uri = new Uri("www.example.com");
var resp = await client2.GetAsync(web_uri);
var resp_to_str = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
RootObject omyclass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resp_to_str); //pass the response string here.
```

---

**Updated from OP's comment:**

`textBlock2.Text = omyclass + "----!";` will not work because omyclass is `RootObject`, not a `string`

You have to get the info you need and append it to `textBlock2`:

`textBlock2.text = omyclass.Sex + "----!";`

---

**UPDATE 2 (OP get string as key value pair):**

Usage: `textBlock2.text = omyclass + "----!";`

Override `RootObject.ToString()` and use `Reflection` to get properties & property values

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public List<Member> members { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var values = new List<string>();
        foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            values.Add(property.Name + ": " + property.GetValue(this));
        }
        return string.Join(", ", values);
    }
}
```

Comment: @kienct189 After that, i am printing on textview in local emulator(windows 10) by textBlock2.Text = omyclass + "----!" which is not printing or showing those values(output).

Comment: ! Thanks! Finally i was able to see one value in emulator since from morning. How do i print whole data in key:value pair in emulator. Like this: `type: A Sex: Male.

Comment: @kienc189 Thanks for your time!! The above function works!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use a **Custom Json formatter** and parse it the way you want.It can be implemented at **framework level** so that all data is parsed according to your requirements.Inherit the custom formatter from **MediaTypeFormatter**.

Implement the virtual and abstract functions of MediaTypeFormatter.Pasre the data according to your requirements here.

**I have implemented the formatter this way and it even parses complex data to match the data that i want.**

Comment: Would you mind sharing a basic example! That would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When serializing complex Json if not deserialized correctly the value becomes null.For deserializing complex Json use JsonMediaTypeFormatter.
**My Example**
 In your config File add

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonNetFormatterDecide());  // My custom formatter
       config.Formatters.Insert(1, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());//Default Formatter
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`
```

So i used my custom formatter for all get operations.Format the data as i want and sent to client.The problem i faced was while accepting complex Json data(such as Jsonarrays within Jsonobjects). So in my config file i added the  JsonMediaTypeFormatter() in index 1 of Config.formatters.

In my custom formatter

```
public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
{
    return false;
}
```

This makes JsonMediaTypeFormatter which is a very popular formatter to Deserialize complex data to do the deserialization.

**The bottomline is that you can use `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` toDeserialize complex Json Data**

It has some predefined functions to deserialize.

**By looking at your Json it seems as if Json arrays within Json objects is the reason why your Json is not deserialing correctly**

**If you plan to write your custom Json formatter** ,You can implement at framework level like

```
public class JsonNetFormatterDecide : MediaTypeFormatter
{   
    //......
    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return false; //this causes the // project to use the second formatter in the config file ie,JsonMediaTypeFormatter  or the //default Json Formatter
    }
}
```